# questions on conditional operator in java

Tags: java, programming-languages, operators, conditional-operator

I hava read from Khalid Mugal and others that the conditional operator is right associative.

Can someone explain to me what this means and show me a simple example?

Comment: In what field of computer science is your question directed?

Comment: 7 question asked and yet no answer received !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional Operator [?:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) is [right associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) because right side evaluates first

Explaniation 
A simple expression of conditional operator is

```
condition ? value if true : value if false
```

and an example is

```
boolean ? (10+20):(30+40)
```

in any case either true or false, its evaluate/calculate values on right side first then returns value according to condition

**[Further Explaination](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/jsspec11/expr.htm#1004949):**
It is syntactically right-associative (it groups right-to-left), so that a?b:c?d:e?f:g means the same as a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g)).

Also consider Wiki defination

"The **associativity (or fixity)** of an **operator** is a property that determines **how operators of the same precedence are grouped in the absence of parentheses**."

Hopes that helps

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because the average programmer will expect it to evaluate the boolean expression first and then decide to evaluate the according value. It is after all a short notation for an if/else structure

Comment: public class RightAssociative
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   int i=10;
    int j=true?0:++i;
    System.out.println(i);
   }
    
} //i value 10 instead of 11 according to u ,thanks

Comment: @Gressie and @yagnya plz read "Further Explaination and see link"

Comment: @Imran your further explanation clearly states "The operand not chosen is not evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional expression." which proves my point. (10+20) or (30+40) is only evaluated once the boolean expression indicates it should. Not doing so would waste computing time

Comment: ya its evaluate once onec and relevant but i was talking about evaluation path.

Answer (score 2):

It is right-associative because it is specified as such in the [Java Language Specs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25):

> The conditional operator is syntactically right-associative (it groups right-to-left), so that a?b:c?d:e?f:g means the same as a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g)).

The quote from the original spec provides an example (or at least something, that can be used to write a quick `main` based demo in Java)